Сonvergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha} \sin(e^x)dx$
I want to know the convergence and absolutely convergence of this inetral
$\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha} \sin(e^x)dx$
My try:
$t=e^x$ and $I=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^\alpha t}{t}\sin t dt$
Than, by Dirichlet's test it is converging if $\alpha > 0$. If $-1<\alpha\le 0$, than $I<\int_1^2 \frac{\ln^\alpha t}{t}dt+\ldots$, which is converging, but i don't know what to do if $\alpha \le -1$? And i truly don't understand absolutely converging.

For $\alpha \leq -1$ consider what the integrand $x^\alpha\sin(e^x))$ looks like near zero. Maybe use a comparison test.
Next, by definition, it absolutely converges if $\int_0^\infty |x^\alpha\sin(e^x)|dx$ or equivalently $\int_1^\infty |\ln^\alpha(t) \frac{\sin(t)}{t}|dt$ converges. Your idea of splitting up the integral could also help here.

Thanks a lot, can you please write a full solution, if you understand?
